# How to add line to global.sbt with Intellij IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I want to enable Scala Test

```
 by first adding this line to ~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt:

resolvers += "Artima Maven Repository" at "http://repo.artima.com/releases"
```

How to do this with IJ?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA is designed to work on the project files, but you can also open non-project files for editing using `File` | `Open` menu.

Comment: not quite understand your question: 1) you don't need to add that resolver in order to enable scalatest 2) why not edit (or copy into) global.sbt with the lightweight editors?

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable the Artima SuperSafe Compiler Plugin, you do need to enable an additional resolver. This is distinct from ScalaTest, which is just the testing library. The compiler plugin offers the following features from the site:

> Artima SuperSafe is a commercial Scala compiler plugin with a free Community Edition that checks ScalaTest/Scalactic === and matcher expressions for correctness.

IntelliJ's sbt settings are located at `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > sbt`[image: Global SBT Settings]

Unless you have a very bespoke installation, the bundled sbt will read from
`~/.sbt/1.0` for global plugins and other settings. So if you add or create a file in that directory (i.e. `~/.sbt/1.0/global.sbt` and add the following line to that file:

```
resolvers += "Artima Maven Repository" at "http://repo.artima.com/release
```

You should be able to use the plugin you added to your `project/plugins.sbt` file for your specific project, which probably looks something like this:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.artima.supersafe" % "sbtplugin" % "1.1.3")
```

You may need to restart the sbt shell to have those settings take effect. Hopefully that should help.